# Library for reservation scheduling for accommodation on an ASP.NET web site

Tags: asp.net, scheduling

I am looking for a library to facilitate a nice UX for displaying a reservation calendar for a small bed and breakfast place.  I would like to be able to show a calendar with maybe two views, being a high level 'year' view, showing high and low seasons, and basic indication of existing reservations, and a 'month' view showing more exact reservation details and allowing a user to submit a reservation request by using buttons or context menus.

I am in a very early part of the life cycle for this project and am looking for suggestions here rather than specific solutions, but what libraries and components are out there that I can look at and draw up a shortlist from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity and speed of execution, I would consider the Telerik controls. If you're able to implement this in Silverlight then the calendar/schedule control pretty much gives you everything that you're asking for, really:
http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#ScheduleView/FirstLook

They also have a fair amount of configurable controls for .NET and JavaScript as well:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/functionality/specialdays/defaultcs.aspx

If you just want a solution that doesn't require integration into the .NET code then the jQueryUI JavaScript library may be useful. It merely takes data coming back from the page load or a service request and displays it for you:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/

Hope that's helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably look at the jQueryUI side of things.  The Telerik stuff is great but a bit price for just this job, right now.

Comment: The Telerik controls are a great investment if you are going to develop multiple sites over time, well worth the money saved in time not spent coding UI. The jQueryUI is a great alternative, though. You're in good hands either way.

Answer (score 0):

Ext JS could be a viable option, then you could use a scheduling product that I have created. This demo could be pretty close to what you need: http://ext-scheduler.com/examples/html5/html5.html (try it in FireFox or Chrome for best experience). Integrates easily with ASP.NET too.

Other options would be FullCalendar (jQuery), ASPxScheduler by DevExpress.

Comment: Hm, I've used ExtJS before and been happy, so I'll give this a look, thanks.